# Unable to Access Springboot @Value Parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, maven

Have Created a simple RestAPI to store a query result from MySQL db to a ArrayList Structure with a simple Controller,Service structure

I am trying to access @Value credentials of MySQL DB which are provided via both application.properties and external arguments. But somehow the values are coming out null. I referred other answers related to same topic and Added a [DataConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029058/error-connecting-to-database-spring-boot) Class too but to no avail

Application runs fine but it shows message that ${spring.datasource.url} cannot be null etc

I have copied the code from a similar designed application where the code was running fine without this issue

Have attached the code and error below

Any help would be appreciated

Controller

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ApiService service;
    
    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping("/get_sql_ds_query")
    public Map<String,Object> getSQLDSQuery(){
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response= service.getServiceFunction();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class ApiService {
    
    @Autowired
    private FileReaderUtility file_read;
    
    public Map<String, Object> getServiceFunction() {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response=file_read.getQueriedSqlData();
        return response;
    }
}
```

A file readerUtility where I intented to run the code actually

```
public void loadData(String url,String user,String password) {
        String query = "select Name,UseCaseKey from RankedPickList_Stories_Master;";
        
        
        try {
            System.out.println("url="+url);
            System.out.println("user="+user);
            System.out.println("password="+password);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            // Create an ArrayList to hold the string values
            // ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                String columnValue1 = rs.getString("column_name_1");
                String columnValue2 = rs.getString("column_name_2");
                String concatenatedValues = columnValue1 + " " + columnValue2;
                sql_data_structure.add(concatenatedValues);
            }

            // Print out the ArrayList
            System.out.println(sql_data_structure);

            // Close the database connection
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }
        }
    
    public Map<String,Object> getQueriedSqlData(){
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        for(String line_l:sql_data_structure) {
            String value_1=line_l.substring(0,StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line_l, " ", 1));
            String value_2=line_l.substring(StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line_l, " ", 1)+1,StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line_l, " ", 2));
            response.put(value_1, value_2);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

DatConfig

```
@Configuration
public class DataConfig {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;


    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .username(userName)
                .password(password)
                .url(url)
                .driverClassName(driverClassName)
                .build();
    }
}
```

POM.XML dependancies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId> 
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId> 
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Calling LoadData here

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Sql2DataStructureApplication {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private static String url;
    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private static String user;
    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private static String password;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReaderUtility file_1 = new FileReaderUtility();
            file_1.loadData(url,user,password);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        SpringApplication.run(Sql2DataStructureApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Log Message

```
url=null
user=null
password=null
SQLException: The url cannot be null
SQLState: 08001
VendorError: 0

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.9)

2023-03-10 20:40:34.618  INFO 43259 --- [           main] c.e.S.Sql2DataStructureApplication       : Starting Sql2DataStructureApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.16 on pop-os with PID 43259 (/home/blesson/eclipse-workspace_2/Sql2DataStructure/target/Sql2DataStructure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war started by blesson in /home/blesson/eclipse-workspace_2/Sql2DataStructure/target)
2023-03-10 20:40:34.622  INFO 43259 --- [           main] c.e.S.Sql2DataStructureApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-10 20:40:35.645  INFO 43259 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-03-10 20:40:35.662  INFO 43259 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 7 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-03-10 20:40:36.362  INFO 43259 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-03-10 20:40:36.375  INFO 43259 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-10 20:40:36.376  INFO 43259 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.71]
2023-03-10 20:40:37.356  INFO 43259 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-10 20:40:37.356  INFO 43259 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2676 ms
2023-03-10 20:40:37.575  INFO 43259 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-03-10 20:40:38.125  INFO 43259 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-03-10 20:40:38.185  INFO 43259 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-03-10 20:40:38.251  INFO 43259 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final
```

Comment: Where is  loadData() called? Please provide the complete utility code.

Comment: Calling loadData() in @SpringApplication part , have made the edit to the draft 
Sorry for the delayed response !!

Comment: Where is `${spring.datasource.url}` being set?  In `application.properties`?

Comment: Yes, its in Application.properties
I am also giving them as an Argument to the jar file 
like this 
```
java -jar Sql2DataStructure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war # --spring.datasource.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_base" --spring.datasource.username="root" --spring.datasource.password="mysql123"
```

Comment: Is that comment character actually in the command-line at the shell?  If so, the `--spring.datasource.url=...` and the rest is ignored when the `java` command runs

Comment: Also, is `--spring.datasource.url` a thing?  Try `-Dspring.datasource.url=...` instead

Comment: One thing you can do to check this in the application, dump the return value of `System.getProperty("spring.datasource.url")`

Comment: I Tried the  `-Dspring.datasource.url=...` part and it started working, cant believe that was the issue, thanks for the help
Not sure how this is `--spring.datasource.url=` method is working in another application that I am running, but certanly will check up with that

Thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The properties are coming as NULL because the corresponding property files aren't loaded until the application starts to run. 
 If you'd like to see how this works put `logging.level.org.springframework.core.env=DEBUG` in your properties file. When you run it again, you can clearly see when the key is found in the logs.

```
2023-03-12T20:18:04.543+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] com.example.app.AppApplication           : Starting AppApplication using Java 19.0.2 with PID 49488 
2023-03-12T20:18:04.557+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] com.example.app.AppApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-12T20:18:07.436+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-03-12T20:18:07.468+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-12T20:18:07.469+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-03-12T20:18:07.761+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-12T20:18:07.766+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3026 ms
2023-03-12T20:18:07.893+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.example.app.AppApplication.url
2023-03-12T20:18:07.893+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.example.app.AppApplication.user
2023-03-12T20:18:07.893+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.example.app.AppApplication.password
2023-03-12T20:18:07.906+05:30 DEBUG 49488 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.datasource.url' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
2023-03-12T20:18:07.910+05:30 DEBUG 49488 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.datasource.username' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
2023-03-12T20:18:07.913+05:30 DEBUG 49488 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.datasource.password' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
2023-03-12T20:18:08.770+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-12T20:18:08.792+05:30  INFO 49488 --- [           main] com.example.app.AppApplication           : Started AppApplication in 5.776 seconds (process running for 7.055)
```

Also please note, you can't use the `@Value` annotation on static fields as Spring doesn't support static field injection. 
If calling `loadData()` before the application runs isn't a necessity, you could instantiate it as a bean. 
For example -

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Config.class);
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;


    @Bean
    public void loadData() {
        LOGGER.info("Load data ... ");
        try {
            LOGGER.info("URL : " + url);
            LOGGER.info("User : " + user);
            LOGGER.info("Password : " + password);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output Logs**

```
023-03-12T20:38:24.124+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] com.example.app.AppApplication           : 
2023-03-12T20:38:24.136+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] com.example.app.AppApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-12T20:38:26.705+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-03-12T20:38:26.741+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-12T20:38:26.742+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-03-12T20:38:27.068+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-12T20:38:27.077+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2746 ms
2023-03-12T20:38:27.210+05:30 DEBUG 49728 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.datasource.url' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
2023-03-12T20:38:27.210+05:30 DEBUG 49728 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.datasource.username' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
2023-03-12T20:38:27.226+05:30 DEBUG 49728 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.datasource.password' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
2023-03-12T20:38:27.226+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] com.example.app.Config                   : Load data ... 
2023-03-12T20:38:27.226+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] com.example.app.Config                   : URL : sample.com
2023-03-12T20:38:27.226+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] com.example.app.Config                   : User : vnk
2023-03-12T20:38:27.226+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] com.example.app.Config                   : Password : password
2023-03-12T20:38:28.274+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-12T20:38:28.298+05:30  INFO 49728 --- [           main] com.example.app.AppApplication           : Started AppApplication in 5.639 seconds (process running for 7.032)
```

I'm quite new to Spring Boot myself so please do let me know if this solution is appropriate. Any feedback on how it can be improved is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The issue got resolved actually 
Was using `--spring.datasource.url=...` instead of `-Dspring.datasource.url=...`
Also accessing static component was done through `System.getPropert('spring.datasource.url')` part

Answer (score 0):

Your file reader utility is not a Spring managed bean. Therefore, the variables will not be initialized.